# How to remove days from datetime.date object

Tags: python, datetime

Let's say, we have this date `2022-01-01`. How can I remove days part from it to get `2022-01`?

I've already tried using strptime `'{:%Y-%m}'.format(dt.strptime(currentDate, '%Y-%m-%d'))` but it gives me this error `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.date`

Comment: `strptime` is used for converting a `str` to a `datetime` object - not sure why you'd use it here

Comment: You should use  `strftime` method instead of  `strptime`.  `strptime` is used in converting a string to a DateTime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `strftime` method:

```py
import datetime as dt

date_object = dt.datetime(2022, 1, 1)

output = date_object.strftime('%Y-%m')
print(output) # 2022-01
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import datetime

dt: datetime = datetime.strptime("2022-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m"))
# 2022-01
```